# SVG. Reverse image using css. Keep image at the same place

Tags: image, css, svg, css-animations

Here is a codepen example https://codepen.io/yury-leonov/pen/rZxxQE

#### Code from example:

```js
$(".example").on("click", function(e){
  $(e.target).toggleClass("reverse");
})
```

```css
.reverse{
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 700px;height: 700px;margin-left: 100px">
    <svg viewBox="-200 0 700 700">
        <image class="example" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/3d/6a/6f3d6aab605e25af947d804c4a2cb558.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" x="50", y="50"/>
        <image class="example" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/3d/6a/6f3d6aab605e25af947d804c4a2cb558.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" x="100", y="0"/>
      <!--x value can be changed during time-->
    </svg>
</div>
```

#### Issue:

Arrow moves from its position

#### Expected:

Arrow is reversed. Stay at same place. Do it only based on css (without js calculating  final x-value and setting it up)

#### PS:

hardcode for translateX(-???px) is not an option, because there could be many objects which should be reversed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use transform-origin and transform-box

```js
$(".example").on("click", function(e){
  $(e.target).toggleClass("reverse");
})
```

```css
.reverse{
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform-origin: center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 700px;height: 700px;margin-left: 100px">
    <svg viewBox="-200 0 700 700">
        <image class="example" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/3d/6a/6f3d6aab605e25af947d804c4a2cb558.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" x="50", y="50"/>
        <image class="example" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/3d/6a/6f3d6aab605e25af947d804c4a2cb558.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" x="100", y="0"/>
      <!--x value can be changed during time-->
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer of @Robert Longson, the idea was born to make a mini-animation of the characters - girls and a guy.
Their images will rotate, turn away from each other. Other options are possible. In my opinion this should look rather interesting.

*Rotate back and forth of each image after clicking on the selected image.*

```js
$(".example").on("click", function(e){
  $(e.target).toggleClass("reverse");
})
```

```css
.reverse{
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform-origin: center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}
.container {
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" >
    <svg viewBox="0 0 700 700">
        <image class="example" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM5im.png" width="300px" height="450px" x="50", y="50"/>
        <image class="example" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFoj1.jpg" width="300px" height="450px" x="350", y="0"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution but I'm not sure you will like it:
I set transform origin at **half of the image width**(75px) and added the **x coordinate**(50px) so it will be 75+50=125px.

```
.reverse{
    transform-origin: 125px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this solution is not working. Because it's hardcoded. I've added 2-nd array on SVG and how you can check - transform-origin: 125px; -  is working only for one arrow

Comment: Not really, you can use javascript to calculate based on these attributes.

Comment: Please pay attention to "(without js calculating final x-value and setting it up)"
How to make it with JS - I know. How to make it without - I can't find solution.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see that. My mistake.